# stemming Indonesian word with Sastrawi

Tags: python, stemming

I have a csv dataset that value of that data right here
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TrCK8.jpg)

So, I want to preprocessing the data. The type of data is text so I will text mining. But I'm confuse about stemming. I have try stemming the data but the result is count of word of all news. I get code reference from my friend but I wanna change. I wanna change that code to improve the result. I hope the result is count of word **every each news**, not split all of news. Plz help me to change code.

Here the code :

```html
import os
import pandas as pd
from pandas import DataFrame, read_csv

data = r'D:/SKRIPSI/sample_200_data.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(data)

print "DF", type (df['content']), "\n", df['content']
isiberita = df['content'].tolist()
print "DF list isiberita ", isiberita, type(isiberita)
df.head()

---------------------------------------------------------

import nltk
import string
import os
import pandas as pd

from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
from Sastrawi.Stemmer.StemmerFactory import StemmerFactory
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
from collections import Counter


path = 'D:/SKRIPSI/sample_200_data.csv'
token_dict = {}

factory = StemmerFactory()
stemmer = factory.create_stemmer()

content_stemmed = map(lambda x: stemmer.stem(x), isiberita)
content_no_punc = map(lambda x: x.lower().translate(None, string.punctuation), content_stemmed)
content_final = []


for news in content_no_punc: 
 word_token = nltk.word_tokenize(news) # get word token for every news (split news into each separate words)
 word_token = [word for word in word_token if not word in nltk.corpus.stopwords.words('indonesian') and not word[0].isdigit()] # remove indonesian stop words and number
 content_final.append(" ".join(word_token))

counter = Counter() # counter initiate
[counter.update(news.split()) for news in content_final] # we split every news to get counter of each words
print(counter.most_common(100))
```

So the result of that code is :

```html
[('indonesia', 202), ('rp', 179), ('jakarta', 160), ('usaha', 149), ('investasi', 136), ('laku', 124), ('ekonomi', 100), ('negara', 86), ('harga', 86), ('industri', 84), ('izin', 84), ('menteri', 83), ('listrik', 79), ('juta', 76), ('pasar', 73), ('tani', 71), ('uang', 71), ('koperasi', 71), ('target', 66), ('perintah', 66), ('saham', 65), ('miliar', 64), ('kerja', 63), ('sektor', 62), ('investor', 61), ('bangun', 60), ('produk', 60), ('pajak', 60), ('capai', 60), ('layan', 58), ('bank', 57), ('produksi', 57), ('modal', 57), ('turun', 57), ('china', 56), ('milik', 55), ('tingkat', 54), ('us', 54), ('triliun', 53), ('tumbuh', 53), ('bkpm', 53), ('impor', 52), ('kembang', 51), ('pt', 49), ('jalan', 49), ('dana', 48), ('bandara', 48), ('negeri', 46), ('rencana', 45), ('nilai', 45), ('temu', 44), ('salah', 42), ('proyek', 41), ('masuk', 41), ('desember', 40), ('langsung', 40), ('hasil', 39), ('butuh', 39), ('rupa', 38), ('biaya', 37), ('kapal', 37), ('rusia', 37), ('franky', 37), ('hadap', 36), ('kredit', 35), ('utama', 35), ('carrefour', 35), ('bijak', 35), ('ikan', 35), ('tanam', 35), ('atur', 34), ('persero', 34), ('kait', 34), ('jam', 34), ('masyarakat', 32), ('gas', 32), ('pakai', 32), ('dagang', 31), ('kondisi', 31), ('transmart', 31), ('lihat', 31), ('bisnis', 31), ('nggak', 31), ('kawasan', 30), ('dorong', 30), ('tutup', 30), ('banding', 30), ('batas', 30), ('terima', 30), ('cepat', 30), ('jasa', 30), ('ton', 29), ('the', 29), ('pln', 29), ('ekspor', 29), ('barel', 29), ('as', 29), ('rumah', 29), ('orang', 28), ('pondok', 28)]
```

I hope anyone can help me to change the code so I can get result **"count of word in every each news(content), not all count word in all news"**. Thankyou.

Comment: how to get nltk corpus for Indonesia language?

Answer (score 2):

If I understand this correctly, your problem isn't directly related to [PySastrawi](https://github.com/har07/PySastrawi).

The problem is that you use `counter.update()` while processing the news data. This, in the end, will return accumulated count of words from all news.
If you want to count words from individual news separately, then you need a separate instance of `Counter` for each news. Something like the following (this will print 100 most common words from each news) :

```
for news in content_final:
    counter = Counter(news.split()) # counter initiate
    print(counter.most_common(100))
```

Complete demo example :

```
>>> content_final = ['foo','foo foo bar','foo baz baz']
>>> for news in content_final:
...     counter = Counter(news.split())
...     print(counter.most_common(1))
...
[('foo', 1)]
[('foo', 2)]
[('baz', 2)]
```

See it live : https://eval.in/664688